# How to automate dependency management using setuptools and pip when I have dependencies on git repos?

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools

I want to find a way to make my package development and use as automatic as possible.

Some of my package's dependencies are self-developed packages which are to be found in a git repository.

When I do `pip freeze`, it lists these git dependencies like so:

```
pandas==0.24.1
...
-e git+https://my/repo.git@ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff#egg=mydependency
```

Since I want to avoid copy-pasting, I do the following to include dependencies in `setup.py`:

```
with open("requirements.txt", "r") as f:
    install_requires = f.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

(I produce `requirements.txt` via `pip freeze > requirements.txt`)

Then, when I try to install the package that has the setup.py described above, I get this error:

```
$ pip install .
Processing /path/to/pkg
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in pkg setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'-e git+h'"
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some important option of `pip freeze` when creating my `requirements.txt`? Am I misunderstanding the whole idea/process of `pip` and `setuptools` in the first place? Or is that idea flawed?

The only fix I can come up with is as ugly as introducing dependencies manually into `setup.py`'s `install_requires` argument. Or maybe that's just the right way to do things?

The problematic dependency should not be published and needs to be installed from git.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/